# Jquery + Bootstrap Modal, open a modal inside the other... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to load the data from ajax inside a bootstrap modal like this:

```
function edit_company_modal(id){

        $.get('/panel/companies/edit/'+id+'/', function(data) {
                    $('#editCompanyModal').modal('show');
                    $('#editCompanyModal').html(data);

                }
        );
        return false;
    }
```

But what is happen is that it is trying to open a modal inside the other, and nothing is show... but the response is right (checked at firebug)

that is how it looks after click event:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="editCompanyModal" aria-labelledby="Edit Company" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
     <div class="modal fade" id="editCompanyModal" aria-labelledby="Edit Company" aria-hidden="true">
```

How should I do something like that?

Thanks

Comment: I would stick with 1 modal modal at a time and use `('#yourmodal .modal-body').html()` to change elements within.

Comment: it because your function complete it's work.Try to use promise.http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the data into the modal's body container.Since we don't have your HTML let's take a general modal structure and apply the jQuery to fill the modal's body after the ajax call. Notice since you are using `data-target` for the button element, you no longer need to use the `.modal('show')`

HTML

```
<button id="editCompany" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCompanyModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="editCompanyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editCompanyModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#editCompany').click(function() {
  //Get value of id
  // id = ???
  $.ajax({
    url: '/panel/companies/edit/'+id+'/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: (data, status, xhr) ->
      $('#editCompanyModal .modal-body').html(data);
  });
});
```